# Create new sheets Named from cells and Auto-Populate with information from Master sheet

Tags: vba, excel, auto-populate

I have a master sheet of names and addresses like this:

```
Company Type        First   Last    TITLE           EMAIL           PHONE       US_MAIL_AD  US_MAIL_ADline2 CITY    STATE   ZIP
A       Telephone   Matt    Smith                   6789@def.com    265-3555    240 N       Indianapolis    IN      2222
B       Water       John    Cook    Design Engineer 12345@abc.com   265-3333    241 N       Indianapolis    IN      22222
```

I also have a second sheet containging a template for a phone log with a header that that will include the addresses, etc. but not in the same row format.

I want excel to automatically create a new sheet for each company, which I have already figured out(below), but I need the new sheets to contain the header from the template sheet populated with the address information. So is there a way to copy in specific cells in the same function as the one that creates the sheets?

```
Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, wrkbk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = wrkbk.Worksheets(SheetName) 'Attempt to set reference to worksheet.
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0) 'Was an error generated - True or False?
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Sub AddSheets()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Project Contact List").Range("B2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        If Not (WorkSheetExists(MyCell.Value, wbToAddSheetsTo)) Then
                Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value
                On Error Resume Next
                ActiveSheet.Name = MyCell.Value
                'If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                '    Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
                'End If
                On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Just copy the relevant range to the sheet you create.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what info you want to transfer, but something like this will do it.

```
Sub AddSheets()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range, ws As Worksheet
Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook

With Sheets("Project Contact List")
    Set MyRange = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If Not WorkSheetExists(MyCell.Value, wbToAddSheetsTo) Then
        Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = MyCell.Value
        MyCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 9).Copy ws.Range("A1")
    End If
Next MyCell

End Sub
```